# Ask to quit application during install on OSX

Tags: macos, installation

I use Iceberg to create my installation pkg and I need to check if previous version of my application is running.

I want to show a dialog like iTunes does during update to terminate the running application.
What is the best way to implement this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Iceberg (I use PackageMaker, myself), but if you *were* using PackageMaker, this would be solved with a pre-install "Quit Application" install action.